dipole-radiation in semiclassical dynamics solid state
Using the semiclassical dynamics in solid state physics (electrons on a lattice with periodic potential, constrained to a band structure), we usually obtain that in the presence of external fields (electric/magnetic), electrons accelerate (as in Bloch oscillations or close orbits in the presence of a magnetic field). This picture is, of course, an approximation we can have when $\Delta r \Delta k\ll1$ and $\Delta r \ll a$ (where $a$ is the lattice constant). When thinking of an accelerating charged particle, we can expect dipole radiation to be radiated from it.
Does it happen? Can one obtain this phenomenon? If not, why? If yes, does it lose energy due to the radiation?
